# javascript being called before validation rule

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

When the user clicks the command button, the action does not fire, but the redirect to the new url does. I want the users record to save (validation rules, etc to get called first), then if it saves ok, let them proceed to the new url.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity"  standardStylesheets="true" extensions="OpportunityController" >
<apex:form >
<center>
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}"  onComplete="openWindow()" value="Change Record Type" />

<script>
function openWindow(){
window.parent.parent.window.location = ("{!redirect}");
}
</script>

</center>
</apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `onComplete` depends on the request being an AJAX request. This only happens when `reRender` is present, even if it has no value. The most usual means of invoking an AJAX request is to use `reRender="form"`, and using `<apex:form id="form">` instead of not providing an ID.
2. You won't be able to determine if the page had an error directly in your function. `onComplete` always fires, even if there were errors. A common mechanism to pass a value back from the controller is through an `apex:inputHidden`. What follows is a common example of how you might detect if the function should redirect.

.

```
<script>
function onComplete() {
    var hasErrorElement = document.getElementById("{!$Component.form.hasError}");
    if(hasErrorElement.value === "false") {
        // perform logic here
    }
}
</script>

<apex:form id="form">
    <apex:commandButton action="{!action}" reRender="form" onComplete="onComplete()" value="Go!"/>
    <apex:inputHidden value="{!hasError}" id="hasError"/>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: good point! 1 up :)

Comment: @sfdcfox can you please elabborate some more on #2 and how i should proceed?

Comment: There's an example in the source I provided. `hasError` could be a string, boolean value, etc. I'd probably recommend a string just for type safety concerns, though.

Comment: @sfdcfox how do i capture the errors in the controller? I need to instantiate the "hasError" value

Comment: `hasErrors` would be a `public string hasErrors { get; set; }`. You'd set it just like any other variable.

Comment: @sfdcfox i don't know how to get the field level security, validation rule errors into the setter in the controller :-/ that's where i've been stuck ...

Answer (score 1):

**Think this way now:**

**1.** You want the action to do the logic. 
 **2.** Why not make the action do the redirection too?

**Follow the code below:**

```
public class OpportunityController {

 //Constructor
 public OpportunityController(){
    //Do onload logic
 }

 //action
 Public PageReference save(){
      //Do the logic for the save

      //Save the record 

      //Redirect
      PageReference redirect = new PageReference ('http://google.com');
      redirect.setRedirect(true);
      return redirect;
 }

}
```

**I feel this should work. Please give it a go!**

Comment: That's perfectly valid, and the most usual way of accomplishing this task. Sometimes, though, you want to do something else besides just a simple redirect that you might want to do client-side, which is why onComplete exists. But this answer would definitely work.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox but my answer was the common way to do it, you approached it differently. Kudos for that! I learnt something today :)

Comment: I definitely agree that for a simple redirect, PageReference is the way to go.